# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Hello everyone please help with my code. The getAllRequest() fetches all user's posts from the database. But edit( should enable the user to edit a post by its id. Whenever I click on the edit button in the frontend, I get the error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Please how do I resolve this error?
Thanks in advance

This is my code

```````
const checkToken = () =>{
    const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
    if(token){
        return token
    }
    window.location.href =`../signin.html`
}

let path = 'http://localhost:5000'
async function getAllRequest(){
    const response = await fetch(`${path}/api/v1/user/entry`, {
      method : "GET",
      headers:{
        "content-type" : "application/json",
        "x-access-token": ` ${checkToken()}`
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(e => e)
if(response.message === "No Response"){
 return   document.getElementById('intro').classList.add('intro--entry--show');
}else if(response.message === "Unathorized!"){
    errorDisplay.innerHTML =`<p>Session has expired</p>`
    errorDisplay.classList.add('user-red')
    return setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href('../signin.html')
    }, 2000);
}else{
  // if response !== No response || unauthorized
  document.getElementById('intro').classList.remove('intro--entry--show');
  // remove the intro--entry--show
  const datas = response.request;
  const container = document.querySelector('.container')
  // for each resource , create a new div
  datas.forEach((data)=>{
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div')
    newDiv.classList.add('user__posts')
    newDiv.innerHTML = `
    <p class="user__post--title title-${data.id}"><b>Title: </b>${data.title}</p><br>
                        <p class="post--date"  ><b>Time: </b>${data.createdon}</p><br>
                        <p class="user__post--description description-${data.id}" ><b>Description</b><br>${data.description}</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-edit" onClick=edit(${data.id})"> Edit</button>
                        <button class="request-save-button save-${data.id}" style="display : none" onClick="save(${data.id})">Save</button>
                        <button class="request-cancel-button cancel-${data.id}" style="display : none" onClick="cancel(${data.id})">Cancel</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-delete" onClick="deleteRequest(${data.id})">Delete</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-view view-${data.id}">View</button>
                        
    `
    container.append(newDiv)
  })

  // add class user__posts to the div
  // set new div to contents
  // append div to the container    
}
  }
  
  getAllRequest();

  async function edit(id){
    const response = await fetch(`${path}/user/entry/modify/${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers:{
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-acess-token": `${checkToken()}`
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(e => e)
if(response.message === 'Diary entry not found!'){
  document.querySelector(`.cancel-${id}`).style.display = 'none';  document.querySelector(`.save-${id}`).style.display = 'none';
}else{
  contentEditable(id)
}
  }
  


function contentEditable(id){
  document.querySelector(`.cancel-${id}`).style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector(`.save-${id}`).style.display = 'block';
  let edit = document.querySelector(`.title-${id}`)
  edit.setAttribute('contenteditable' , 'true');
  edit.classList.add('edit-border');
  let editDescription = document.querySelector(`.description-${id}`)
  editDescription.setAttribute('contenteditable' , 'true');
  editDescription.classList.add('edit-border');
}
`````` 






















`
```````

Comment: `"x-acess-token": `${checkToken()}`  <<< this might be your issue, you mispelled access

Comment: At what line is the `Uncaught Syntax Error`?

Comment: @klaassiek line 1 the html file <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @AlCapwned I have corrected the spelling, still getting the error.

Comment: You spelled `x-access-token` wrong twice in your original question. You should correct the second occurence too, in the `edit` function. The edit request expects a json reponse. You get an html response. That where the error comes from. So something is wrong in the request that makes it impossible for the server to respond with a valid json-thing. Besides that: check the response from the edit request to `${path}/user/entry/modify/${id}` in the network tab of the deveoper tools. It might give you an indication; the http status header will probably show 401, 404 or 400. That is usefull info.